# Integral of convex set

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, convex-analysis, geometric-probability

Let $D$ be a convex set and $X_1,\dots,X_d$ be integrable random variables. If $X= (X_1,\dots,X_d)$ is in $D$ almost surely, 
why is it true that the vector $a= (\mathbb{E}X_1,\dots,\mathbb{E}X_d)$ belongs to $D$ almost surely also?

Here $\mathbb{E}$ denotes the expectation with respect to a probability measure.

Comment: Note that a belongs to D or does not belong to D but that these are "deterministic" statements, not probabilistic ones, hence [a belongs to D almost surely] is odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The true reason is that the mean of every measure is in the convex hull of its support, hence if the support is included in a convex set then the mean is in the convex set.

An elementary approach is to consider an i.i.d. sequence $(X^n)_{n\geqslant1}$ distributed like $X$. For every $n\geqslant1$, $M_n=\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX^k$ is a barycenter of $n$ points of $D$, hence $M_n$ is in $D$ almost surely. Since $M_n\to a$ almost surely, this shows that $a$ is in the closure of $D$.

If $a$ is not in $D$, there exists a closed semi-space $\{x\mid\langle x,u\rangle\geqslant\langle a,u\rangle\}$ which does not intersect $D$. Since $X_1$ is in $D$ almost surely, $Y^1=\langle X^1-a,u\rangle\lt0$ almost surely, which implies that $E[Y^1]\lt0$. Considering $Y^n=\langle X^n-a,u\rangle$ for every $n\geqslant1$, the law of large numbers applied to the i.i.d. sequence $(Y^n)$ implies that $\langle M_n-a,u\rangle=\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nY^k$ converges almost surely to $E[Y^1]\lt0$ although $M_n-a\to0$ when $n\to\infty$. This is absurd, hence $a$ is in $D$.

Comment: Why must there exist a closed semi-space $\{x\mid\langle x,u\rangle\geq \langle a,u\rangle\}$ which does not intersect $D$? As far as I know, without further assumptions on $D$ the separating hyperplane theorem only guarantees the existence of some $u$ such that $\langle x,u\rangle\leq \langle a,u\rangle$ for all $x\in D$.

Comment: @carmichael561 Use "which does not intersect the interior of D" instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364a/03ConvexFunctions.pdf) is a lemma we need: When D is convex, the distance function $f(x) = \inf_{ y \in D}\|x-y\|$ is convex.

Then by Jensen's inequality $ f(E[X]) \leq E[f(X)]$. Since $f(X)=0$ almost sure, we get the distance from $E[X]$ to D is zero, thus the final conclusion.

In some cases(when $D$ is not closed) we add some "almost surely" arguments to avoid  $E[X] \in \partial D$ and $E[X] \not \in D$

Comment: I fail to get the [add some "almost surely"] argument and how it is related to the case when D is not closed.

Comment: @Did: when $D$ is not closed, it's possible that $E[X]=a\in \partial D$ and $a \not\in D$.And in this case $X$ has to be equal to $a$ almost surely in order to have $E(X)=a$ since $a$ is on the border of $D$ and that's contradictory with $X$ almost surly in $D$